# How can I keep spans in the same line vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code in reality:

```css
.notifications_list{
 margin-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 direction: rtl;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.notifications_list li{
 list-style: none;
}
.notification_date_title{
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.note_icon{
}

.note_icon i{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.note_type{
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="notifications_list">
  <div class="notification_date_title">امروز +5</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">2 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">دیروز +10</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">14 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">در هفته گذشته </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span class="note_type">تایید جواب</span><span class="note_date_time">2 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">3 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you see, currently those icons and the texts aren't in the same line:

[image]

And this is expected result:

[image]

**Note:** The direction is right-to-left ..!

Well how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the width of all your icons is the same.

You can use this using this css:

```
.note_icon i {
    width: 20px;
}
```

The problem that you have there is that the icons are not the same width, so the elements near them are not aligned the same way.

> The reason I changed the `i` element and not the `span` is because 
>   `span` elements by default are `inline`, and the `i` element here is `inline-block` (due to the css of fontawesome).
>   `inline` blocks can't have width, so setting the width to the `span` element will not work, while setting the width to the `i` element (which is inline-block) will.

Here is a working version:

```css
.note_icon i {
    width: 20px;
}
.notifications_list{
 margin-top: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 direction: rtl;
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.notifications_list li{
 list-style: none;
}
.notification_date_title{
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.note_icon{
}

.note_icon i{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.note_type{
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="notifications_list">
  <div class="notification_date_title">امروز +5</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">2 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">دیروز +10</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">14 ساعت قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="notification_date_title">در هفته گذشته </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span class="note_type">تایید جواب</span><span class="note_date_time">2 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a><div><span class="note_icon"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span><span class="note_type">رای</span><span class="note_date_time">3 روز قبل</span></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah seems correct, thank you, upvote .. Just as you see, those icons are into `span.note_icon` element. Why not set a `width` to that `span` instead of `i`?

Comment: Added explanation in the answer.

Comment: Just for my information, you are from Israel, right? So how did you understand my question?! It should be pretty vague for you, because your native is English *(which has `ltr` direction)* .. So are you either very clever or that *Israel*  *(in your profile)* isn't true ?

Comment: Yes, I am :) Actually the native language in Israel is Hebrew, which is RTL, however your question is not related to direction or text (RTL/LTR).

Comment: And I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have classes to all of them you can use padding to align them manually. Since their sizes are different I think this would be the easiest and most controllable way.

For example try this:

```
i.fa.fa-sort {
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

By the way the expected result seems the exact same like the "wrong" result... Not sure if that was posted by mistake.